# How to filter ListView (SimpleCursorAdapter) from SearchView?

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, android-filter

I try to deal with ListView and SimpleCursorAdapter and faced with the following problem: I have ListView with SimpleCursorAdapter and SearchView. I try to filter my data in ListView (data from the database) according to the text from SearchView. But when I start app on emulator, app crash with NullPointerException. The error may be what? And everything I do right?

```
public class ListViewFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private static final int CM_DELETE_ID = 1;

public ListView listViewData;
public Button mAddButton, mViewButtonProject, mViewButtonStaff;
public Bundle mBundle;

private DatabaseHelper db;

private SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;

private android.support.v7.widget.SearchView sv;

public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view);

    drawNavigationDrawer();

    returnBundle(savedInstanceState);

    final Context context = this;

    db = new ProjectDatabase(this);
    db.open();

    String[] from = new String[] { db.COLUMN_NAME, db.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textViewName, R.id.textViewDescription };

    scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_item, null, from, to, 0);
    listViewData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewData);
    listViewData.setAdapter(scAdapter);

    sv = (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) findViewById(R.id.action_search);
    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            listViewData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewData);
            SimpleCursorAdapter filterAdapter = (SimpleCursorAdapter)listViewData.getAdapter();
            filterAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

            return false;
        }
    });

    registerForContextMenu(listViewData);

    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

}
```

It is all what I do in my code for the task. Is something I have not done?

The NullPointerException error refers to this line: `sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {...}`

I would be very grateful for any help.

upd: I try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView sv = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String newText) {
            scAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
                @Override
                public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                    Cursor cursor = dbConnector.getFilteredData(constraint.toString()); 
            return cursor;
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

In DB class:

```
public Cursor getFilteredContacts(String filter) {
    return database.query(...);
}
```

Comment: `sv` is simply `null`

Comment: I fix error, but data is not changed when I write text on SearchView. Maybe need to add something else?

Comment: setup `FilterQueryProvider`

Comment: Can you write me an example for my case, please?

Comment: `class MyFilterQueryProvider extends FilterQueryProvider { ...` the filtering is done in `runQuery` method

Comment: I update my post: I try do something like this. This is the right approach? Or it can be somehow easier? Using exactly the adapter filter.

Comment: what can be easier than calling `setFilterQueryProvider` and simple extending an abstract class and implementing its one method? is it complex? btw `setFilterQueryProvider` should be called once, for example where you are calling `setAdapter` also why did you delete `filterAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);`?

Comment: Yes it complex for me because I do not understand how it work. How to link the class with the code that I've got. Maybe if you describe in more detail the possible ways of the decision, some of the same stupid as me can figure out how to do it.

Comment: I dont understand what I must write in runQuery, what I must return?

Comment: the filtered `Cursor`, something like this: http://pastebin.com/3ekEWxgp

Comment: Thank you for your patience!